# monkeyrunner wait for web login result

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i have a problem when using monkeyrunner to test my app to connect xmpp server. 
After click login button, it will try to connect xmpp server.

`#press login button
print "press login button"
easy_device.touch(By.id('id/loginlogin'),MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)`

If connect to xmpp server successfully, a textview will shows 'success', ortherwise it shows 'failed'. 
I want to get the text form this textview then collect the logs until the textview get xmpp connection result.

```
targetText = 'success'
running = True;
while running:
    getText = easy_device.getText(By.id('id/gridviewTitle')).encode('utf-8')
    print getText
    if getText.find('success') < 0:
        print 'not find success'
        MonkeyRunner.sleep(6)
    else:
        print 'find success'
        running = False
else:
    print 'While loop over'
```

I get log by:

```
def log(fn, device):
    msg = device.shell('logcat -v time -d')
    f_log = open(fn, 'at')
    if msg is None:
        msg = 'None'
    f_log.write(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    f_log.close()   
    device.shell('logcat -c')

print 'Write logs'
log(logcatname, device) # Write logs
```

While I run the monkeyrunner script, I also check logcat form Eclipse.
I found that the connection thread was supended, and after monkeyrunner script run finish, it continue to connect to xmpp server. 
here is the log from Eclipse:

```
09-09 16:59:24.954: I/Androidpn_ServiceManager(20901): serviceThread.start
09-09 16:59:24.957: I/Androidpn_ServiceManager(20901): serviceThread.run
09-09 16:59:25.082: D/Androidpn_NotificationService(20901): onStart()...
09-09 16:59:49.428: D/Androidpn_NotificationService(21155): onCreate()...
09-09 16:59:49.494: D/Androidpn_NotificationService(21155): deviceId=860898020057333
09-09 16:59:49.510: D/Androidpn_NotificationService(21155): onStart()...
```

After NotificationService strat about 25s, this thread continue run after monokeyrunner script finished. 
This cause that i cannot get the logs for connection.
I tried to increase MonkeyRunner.sleep(30) before check result form textview, but no help, it seems that monkeyrunner only invoke one thread at the moment. 
Is there anyone who can help me about this? Thanks in advance!!!